Children's TV-show on VHS about talking animals
Basically there were animals that could talk, various animals ranging from an ant to an elephant. I think the title has "Animals" in it.
It was a cartoon and I had it on VHS, and there were about 10 different VHS tapes and 3-5 short episodes per tape. I was very young, between 5-10ish, so I'd say the show was released between 1995-2005. It was in English (unsure if UK or US).
I remember there was an elephant. There was also a worm that, in one episode, realized it was bald and decided to glue a wig on its head with superglue...

The answer is: Animal Stories.

Animal Stories is a British pre-school animated television series. Cartoon Network TOO began airing this program on 5 June 2006. It also aired on Playhouse Disney in the United States from 1999 to 2005. Animal Stories began airing on Tiny Pop in September 2013. The series gained a 2001 Children's BAFTA for Best Pre-school Animation.
Every episode centers on a different individual animal, who is unique in personality. Every animal story is in rhyme. There are morals in the stories told in rhyming couplets.

